# Update ObservableCollection between Viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I have shared an observableCollection between two ViewModels. When I initiate the viewmodel the observablecollections in both ViewModels work fine, but when I make changes in the source ObservableCollection it doesn't update it in the ObservableCollection in the second ViewModel. How can I make the second observalbeCollection receive the changes made in the first ObservableCollection.

VM 1

```
public Class VM1
{
    private ObservableCollection<CameraPackage> _cameraPackagesPerScene = new ObservableCollection<CameraPackage>();
    public ObservableCollection<CameraPackage> CameraPackagesPerScene
    {
        get { return _cameraPackagesPerScene; }
        set { _cameraPackagesPerScene = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
 }
```

VM2

```
public Class VM2
{
     public ObservableCollection<CameraPackage> CameraPackagesPerSceneAndPartials { get; set; }

     public VM2 (VM1 vm1)
     {
           CameraPackagesPerSceneAndPartials = new ObservableCollection<CameraPackage>(vm1.CameraPackagesPerScene);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass ViewModels into other ViewModels constructor, makes testing harder and cause them to be tightly coupled. Consider using messager/messagebus/event aggregator instead to communicate such changes between views

Comment: Are you using any mvvm framework?

Comment: @IgorQuirino I'm using galasoft mvvmlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create new ObservableCollection based on other OC. Just share one instance to both ViewModels:

```
public VM2 (VM1 vm1)
{
      CameraPackagesPerSceneAndPartials = vm1.CameraPackagesPerScene;
}
```

Or inject only collection to the second ViewModel:

```
public VM2 (ObservableCollection<CameraPackage> cameraPackagesPerSceneAndPartials)
{
      CameraPackagesPerSceneAndPartials = cameraPackagesPerSceneAndPartials;
}
```

Other way to reduce the coupling is to using [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or other [event-based patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745866.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mvvmlight messenger to interchange messages from viewmodels.

This is a Nice way to do this. See the sample below:

**SENDING:**

```
// Sends a notification message with a Person as content.
var person = new Person { FirstName = "Marco", LastName = "Minerva" };
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<Person>(person, "Select"));
```

**RECEIVING:**

```
// Registers for incoming Notification messages.
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<Person>>(this, (message) =>
{
    // Gets the Person object.
    var person = message.Content;

    // Checks the associated action.
    switch (message.Notification)
    {
        case "Select":
            break;
        case "Delete":
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

**FROM TUTORIAL:**

https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/how-to-send-string-and-content-messages-with-mvvm-light-messenger/